# Difference in the solutions of the linear regression problem: python-statsmodels versus python-sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, statsmodels

I have read in some [blogs](https://medium.com/@hsrinivasan2/linear-regression-in-scikit-learn-vs-statsmodels-568b60792991) (I have not tested by myself) that (1)  scikit-learn is slightly faster than statsmodels for 1,000 or less observations, this difference is not significant per the t-test analysis; (2) Sci-kit learn is significantly faster for datasets with more than 1,000 observations.

I also took a look at the source code of the implementations, but it is not clear for me exactly why one is faster than the other. It seems that scikit learn uses the lapack implementation. Is this the only reason, since it is implemented in Fortran? On the other hand, it seems that statsmodels has its own implementation, but I am not sure about that.

Can anyone please clarify the methods are used? Anyway, which methods are used in any of them? How the pseudo inverse matrix is evaluated in any of the cases?

Comment: Both sklearn and statsmodels use SVD/pinv based computation by default for OLS. So, there should not be much difference in computing the parameter estimates. However, `fit` in statsmodels includes additional computation for inference, e.g. covariance of parameter estimates, matrix rank of X.

Comment: I don't know if sklearn switches algorithm for some cases. E.g. there are faster algorithms when there are many observations but at the cost of numerical precision. The default in statsmodels OLS is always LAPACK svd based `pinv`. (Which LAPACK algorithm and whether parallel computing in LAPACK is used might also affect speed in some cases.)